# Отличие is от as в pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

В Oracle при описании процедур и функций секцию объявления локальных переменных можно начать с ключевых слов `as` и `is`. Какая между ними разница?

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает что никакой

Answer (score 5):

**as** и **is** похожи друг на друга, но есть небольшая разница:

- Они синонимы при создании процедур или пакетов
- При создании курсора или таблицы они отличаются

---

Например, это будет работать:

```
cursor test_cursor
is
select * from emp;
```

... а это уже нет:

```
cursor test_cursor
as
select * from emp;
```

Аналогично с таблицами - этот код работает:

```
create table test_table as
select sysdate from dual
```

А этот уже выдаст ошибку "отсутствует или неверна опция":

```
create table test_table is
select sysdate from dual
```

---

**<sub>[Источник.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230348/what-is-the-difference-between-as-and-is-in-an-oracle-stored-procedure)</sub>**

Answer (score 1):

Разницы нет никакой. Ключевые слова `is` и `as` являются синонимами, поставляемые, для того, чтобы сделать код более удобным для чтения. Например:

```
FUNCTION f IS ...

CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT ...
```

Comment: Указывайте [источник ответа](http://stackoverflow.com/a/230388/2907755).

Answer (score 1):

Да, только семантическая разница. Я обычно использую as при создании пакетов

create ... as - Создать как...

и is при определении процедур и функций

procedure ... is - Процедура - есть...